# DateTime Property of ViewModel wouldn't bind

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

The problem is I have this datetime property for which I have used Jquery datepicker. But now when I change date and post the form the value is not getting posted rather a default is being stored in the database. Any idea what have I been missing?
P.S in the view when I inspect the element I don't see the value getting changed when I change the date from the calender..it remains static.

This is my ViewModel

```
public class ProfileChangeViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "BMDC Registration Validity")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",
    ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]      
    public DateTime BMDCValidityUpto { get; set; }

}
```

This is the code in my View:

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.BMDCValidityUpto, new { @class = "control-label col- sm-3" })
<div class="col-sm-9">
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.BMDCValidityUpto, new { htmlAttributes = new {  @class = "form-control" }, })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BMDCValidityUpto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
</div>
```

And this is my DatePicker Code:

```
$('#BMDCValidityUpto').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    "setDate": new Date(),
    "autoclose": true,
    minDate: Date.parse("1900-01-01"),
    maxDate: Date.parse("2100-01-01"),
    yearRange: "1900:+nn"
});
```

Comment: What is the culture of the server? Is it one that accepts dates in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Comment: not really...It shows date in that format. @StephenMuecke

Comment: Your server must also have a culture that matches the format - e.g. in the `web.config` file - `<system.web><globalization culture="en-AU" uiCulture="en-AU" /> ..... </system.web>` or you must use a custom `ModelBinder`